# Spring: Cannot get bean by using @Component and @Bean

Tags: spring, annotations, components, javabeans

I'm new in Spring framework. 
I try to config 2 beans with @Bean annotation within @Component. 
After that, I try to getBean (by name), I got a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException. 
Please help me to resolve it.

***Here is my code:***
- **The component:**

```
package com.example.component;

@Component
public class FactoryMethodComponent {

 private static int i;

 @Bean
 @Qualifier("public")
 public TestBean publicInstance() {
    return new TestBean("publicInstance");
 }

 @Bean
 @Qualifier("tb1")
 public TestBean1 publicInstanceTB1() {
    return new TestBean1(publicInstance());
 }
}
```

-**The xml configuration file: app-context.xml**.

```
<beans ...>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.*" />
</beans>
```

-**The test code:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:app-context.xml" })
public class ComponentBeanTest {
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println(((TestBean1)context.getBean("tb1")).getTestBean().getMethodName());
    System.out.println(publicTestBean.getMethodName()); 
}
}
```

-**Exception:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean 
>       named 'tb1' is defined
>         at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:577)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1111)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1127)
>         at com.example.proxy.ComponentBeanTest.test(ComponentBeanTest.java:38)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `@Component` with `@Configuration` which indicates that a class declares one or more @Bean methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime.

```
@Configuration
public class FactoryMethodComponent {

 private static int i;

 @Bean
 @Qualifier("public")
 public TestBean publicInstance() {
    return new TestBean("publicInstance");
 }

 @Bean
 @Qualifier("tb1")
 public TestBean1 publicInstanceTB1() {
    return new TestBean1(publicInstance());
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. It work fine. If I keep Component annotation, it will work fine with Autowired, but cannot use context.getBean("tb1"). I don't understand this mechanism.

Comment: When using Component, the class is a valid candidate for autowire as the methods marked with Bean are treated as normal method declaration, no bean generated. But when using Configuration, methods marked with Bean are treated as generating spring beans and beans are generated.

Comment: Thank you. I want to get more detail about this problem. Can you give me the document or key for research?

Comment: Look into spring official reference and API doc for more.

Comment: It's nice. Thanks so much.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it really helped. Thanks.

Comment: It's ok. :))))))